# error on liquibase bean after change password for postgres in JHipster

Tags: postgresql, jhipster, liquibase

I am new on JHipster and has been creating a new gateway project with

- OAuth(Keycloak)
- Postgres for both dev and prod
- jhipster registry
- gradle

once I get this created run well, I am using docker container to run this hence `docker-compose -f app.yml up` run well, but the project has **keycloak database** in h2 and **gateway database** in **postgres**.
I made the changes needed to start Postgres container with 2 databases gateway and postgres with user/password as the database name.

when I start the application with `docker-compose -f app.yml up` registry, keycloak and postgres start well but the gateway application throw exception on liquibase bean creation.

```
Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/plc/terminalx/gateway/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
 Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provid
```

I have updated the password for the database on **application-prod.yml** like this

```
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gateway
    username: gateway
    password: gateway
jpa:
    database-platform: io.github.jhipster.domain.util.FixedPostgreSQL82Dialect
    database: POSTGRESQL
    show-sql: false
```

also updated the **liquibase.gradle** adding the arguments for password

```
args "--username=gateway"
args "--password=gateway"
```

and I am not overriding the values on app.yml for docker hence should be the unique place application-prod.yml, should I change it in another place?

Note I build the application with `gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage`before to run docker-compose.

Comment: liquibase.gradle is almost never used. Never put real passwords in application-prod.yml use placeholders that refer to environment variable and alternatively delete application-prod.yml from your git repository soi that it does not get included in your jar/war, use an external file (see spring boot docs)

Comment: You use the registry so make sure you have defined application properties for your apps (gateway and services) in the registry see http://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/#spring-cloud-config

Comment: ok, thank you, seems that I need to move the configuration files in my registry.
I created a gateway-prod.yml with the configuration needed and this is working.

Comment: Yes that's exactly it  You can also create an application-prod.yml in same location to define all properties common to all your apps. Check spring cloud config server doc, it's well explained.